# Strophe add Roster Contact

Tags: javascript, xmpp, openfire, strophe

i am currently working on a 'Add Roster Contact" functionality.

**1) I add a new Contact to my Roster with:**

```
var iq = $iq({type: "set"}).c("query", {xmlns: "jabber:iq:roster"}).c("item"  {jid:"test@hostname.de/test",name:"test"});
Chat.connection.sendIQ(iq);
```

The Contact is added successfully to my Roster.

**2) Send presence stanza of type 'subscribe' to the new contact ('test'):**

```
var subscribe = $pres({to: test@hostname.de/test, type: "subscribe"});
Chat.connection.send(subscribe);
```

That works, but not every time:

When the person i am adding to my roster ('test') **has
currently no active session (is not logged in)**, i get a
subscription type of 'none' for the sender, and also
a subscription type of 'none' for 'test'.

**So:**

Receiver 'Test':  Subscription 'None'

Sender 'me': Subscription 'None'

When the person iam adding to my roster has an active
session, the expected subscription-types 'to' and 'from' are successfully set.

**Any idea ?**

Answer (score 5):

Don't use a resource on the to address in the subscription request:

```
var subscribe = $pres({to: "test@hostname.de", type: "subscribe"});
Chat.connection.send(subscribe);
```

When the user comes online later, they should get notified of your request, and can reply with a `<presence type="subscribed"/>` stanza.  If you put a resource on the to address, odd routing rules may come into play that don't cause your request to be stored.